# Can't debug unit tests in Jetbrains Rider

Tags: .net, rider

The same tests run and debug properly in Visual Studio, so this is clearly a Rider issue.

The tests run, but as soon as I try and debug them I get an error message that is entirely useless.

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\JetBrains Rider 2019.3\bin\runnerw64.exe" "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\JetBrains Rider 2019.3\lib\ReSharperHost\JetBrains.Debugger.Worker.exe" --mode=client --frontend-port=60694 "--plugins=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\JetBrains Rider 2019.3\plugins\rider-unity\dotnetDebuggerWorker"
One or more errors occurred.
```

That's all I get.

My debug mode is set to Portable, if it wasn't the tests wouldn't run in VS. But they do.

Also when I try and debug my tests they just stick on pending.

What else could be causing my tests not to debug?

Here's my csproj for my test project.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
    <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.13.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Moq" Version="4.13.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestAdapter" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestFramework" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="1.2.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\sw.cldflt.policymanager.api\sw.cldflt.policymanager.api.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Have you tried newer Rider version?

Comment: 4 months later, I have the same issue. Did you figured this one out ?

Comment: @MaxouMask Yes! It turns out all I needed to do was update Rider to the newest version. Give that a try.

Comment: Actually did and it worked. Thanks.